# Which task groups and permissions to use

Tags: tasks

I have a workflow site  that creates tasks(tasksite). I also have a number of departments that need to complete the tasks.

What permissions would I need to give to department to complete the tasks in tasksite ?

Is there a way to prevent department 1 and department 2 form completing one anothers tasks in tasksite?

Are there any default sharepoint groups I should be using ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The highest level permissions needed would be Edit, which is covered by Contribute.  IIf you don't want them deleting things, create a custom permission level based on contribute but deselect delete items and use that.

In the list settings you can specify who can edit what items.  By default, list items are set to be read by all and edited by all.  It can be changed to edit only their own.